# Extracting a value to use in a command-line argument from a tab-separated file

Tags: bash, command-line

If I have a file `runtime.tsv` as

```
preprocessingTime_ms  1164
samplingTime_ms 17741
```

where the first space is a tab and the second is a space. How can I read `samplingTime_ms` as an argument to pass on to java?

Basically I need to pass to java like

```
java -Xmx2g matching.PermutationESS\ 
        --runtime 17741/1000
```

to execute in Mac command line.

Comment: `awk '{ print $2; }' runtime.tsv` would output both values. I know this is not a complete answer but it's a start. `cut` could also be used but with tab + space it makes more sense to use `awk`

Comment: @RyanNerd, keep in mind that in awk, a block is only run on records that match its condition. `awk '$1 == "samplingTime_ms" { print $2 }'`, then, will only print the second field where the first one has the desired value. (The default condition is always-true, but if you provide your own it's applied instead; just like if you don't provide a block but only have a condition, the default one is `{ print $0 }`, writing the entire line to output).

Answer (score 1):

Use a command substitution to interpolate the result of extracting the value from the input file.

```
java -Xmx2g matching.PermutationESS  --runtime $(
  awk -F '\t' '$1 == "samplingTime_ms" {
    print $NF}' runtime.tsv)/1000
```

If the second line is space-separated, take out the `-F '\t'` (this detail is a bit unclear in your question).

If you want the division to be calculated,

```
java -Xmx2g matching.PermutationESS  --runtime $(
  awk -F '\t' '$1 == "samplingTime_ms" {
    print $NF/1000}' runtime.tsv)
```

Comment: Thanks, but was wondering if there is a good way to make the double division works

Comment: Do you want Awk to perform the division for you? Just `print $NF/1000` and correspondingly remove the string `/1000` after the command substituion

Comment: Sorry I'm very unfamiliar with command line, can you please give a bit more details? Yes I would like to divide the number that I read before I passed to the argument.

Comment: See updated answer.  There are absolutely no additional details which weren't in the comment above so if there is something you still need help with you need to be more specific.